# Merge multiple numpy arrays over same first dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nested-lists, numpy-slicing

I have two numpy arrays `a` and `b` with the same first dimension e.g. `a.shape -> (3, 100)` and `b.shape -> (3, 20, 20)`.

I need to have them converted (*as efficiently as possible*) into an array (or nested list or dict?) `ab` that has the same first dimension (here `3`).
So when I call `ab[1]` it should return something like `[a[1], b[1]]` (or put differently `ab[:][0] == a` and `ab[:][1] == b`).

I feel like this an easy problem, but I don't know what to search for and I have been sitting on this for way too long already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to create a combined NumPy array with arrays of different shapes.  What you could do is use a list and put them in the same rows.

```
ab = [[a[i],b[i]] for i in range(3)]
(ab[0][0] == a[0]).all()
>>>True
```